# Unity Game On Huawei P30 display abnormal?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, game-development

I create a game by Unity Editor. And build an apk file, then install it on my Huawei P30 mobile. But it display out of my expection totally. In Unity Simulation, is fine, as well as on Google Pixel phone. Why P30 not correct.

I try install it on other phone, it's fine.

Comment: can you specify more , the description of your question isn't enough !! What display ? is it the UI display ? or something else ?

Comment: @thunderkill Yeah, The UI. I doubt it's about resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks different, due to different aspect ratio / resolution.
[Check out how to build a game for different resolutions.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)
In addition: check out the [device simulator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.device-simulator@3.0/manual/index.html) to have a preview of how the game is gonna look on the mobile screen of different devices.

Comment: Yeah，I check my phone setting，and found the screen resoulution in SMART mode. then it will dynamically adjust. When I change to 2340*1080, the UI will display as expectation. Thx